# Output saying integer is NaN

Tags: jquery, html, nan

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/VSvHE/3/)

I am making a social button, and I'm trying to make the count so It doesn't say:

> 1 people have liked this

I have succeeded in doing this, but when you click the second time, it says:

> NaN people have liked this

HTML:

```
 <div id='g'><div id='n' style='display: inline-block'>0</div> people have liked this</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($('#n').html() == 1) {
    u = "1 person has liked this";
    $('#g').html(u);
} else {
    var g = parseInt($('#n').html());
    var h = g + 1;
    var v = "people have liked this";
    $('#g').html(h + " " + v);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic of this is a lot more complex than it needs to be. Along with the single letter `id` attributes it's hard to read. Try this:

```
<button id="b">
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/ToZz7PB.png'></img>
</button>
<div style='display: inline-block; font-family: Helvetica'>
    <div id='g'>
        <span id='n'>0</span>
        <span class="message">people have liked this</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$("#b").click(function () {
    var count = +$('#n').text() + 1;
    var message = count == 1 ? 'person has liked this' : 'people have liked this';
    $('#n').text(count);
    $('.message').text(message);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VSvHE/5/)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of using the `people have liked this` as a `div`/`fan`

Comment: You don't need `#g` anymore, after using your method. Do you?

Comment: No, you could remove that. I would also give `#b` and `#n` more meaningful names.

Answer (score 1):

When you update #g 's html, you remove the #n div, so when you're looking for it in the code, it doesn't exist..